# Invoke Method in React Component after completion of API call in react redux saga

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

In my React ComponentDidMount, i am calling an asynchronous action which will invoke API in redux saga.
Now i have a method in my component which should be invoked after API call is completed.

```
comnponentDidMount{
Action Call(); // API call  in redux Saga
Method Call();
console.log('Done')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

      if (prevProps.sp !== this.props.sp && !this.props.sp.fetching) {
         //do whatever you want on finish of api call 
      }
  }
```